# Erro ao passar parâmetro para a função

Tags: c#, uri

Perdi o acesso total de meus sites e estou tentando passar os *posts* dele para um novo.
Estou com um código que lê o *sitemap* dele e pega as *urls* e outro que pega a *url*, separa a parte que preciso e posta em meu novo site.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var website = XMLReader("SITE");
    Postagem(website.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Total de Posts adicionados: " + website.Count());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Ao passar meu site como parâmetro ao `XMLReader` ele lê o *sitemap* e me retorna as *urls* tudo certo.

Ao passar estas *urls* para a função `Postagem`, com o `Try/Catch`, ele me devolve o erro:

> Error: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Mas se eu passar :

```
Postagem("LINK DO POST");
```

Ele posta tudo certo. Qual seria o erro? Não achei nada pela net.

```
private static void Postagem(string website)
{
    try
    {
        string link = "SITE";
        string username = "USER_WP";
        string password = "SENHA_WP";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument resultat = web.Load(website);
        string titulopost = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-title')]")[0].InnerHtml;
        string conteudo = resultat.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'entry-content')]")[0].InnerHtml;
        var wp = new WordPressWrapper(link + "/xmlrpc.php", username, password);
        var post = new Post();
        Console.WriteLine("Adicionando post: " + titulopost);

        post.DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(0);
        post.Title = titulopost;
        post.Body = conteudo;

        wp.NewPost(post, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola. Coloque o código do método `Postagem(...)` para o podermos ajudar.

Comment: Pronto! Adicionei o código...

Comment: Separados eles funcionam 100%, tentar juntar eles que está sendo um problema...

Comment: Qual o valor que esta na variável `website` quando a excepcao ocorre?

Comment: Error: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: Este é o erro...
O valor de website é "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"

Comment: Creio que o erro esteja em:
Postagem(website.ToString());
Mas não achei outro jeito ...

Comment: @RaulCorreia No `main`, coloque um `Console.WriteLine(website);` qual o valor retornado?

Comment: ja arrumei, usei um simples código:

Comment: var total = website.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
            {
                Postagem(website[i]);
            }